# The problem while installing tensorflow-gpu?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have installed tensorflow-gpu to my pc. Then I created an environment in anaconda(tf_gpu) to use tensorflow-gpu.

After I open anaconda prompt and activate tf_gpu environment, I type:

```
python
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

I get this output:

```
2019-07-20 16:47:07.670932: I 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports 
instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX 
AVX2
2019-07-20 16:47:07.843280: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 0 
with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 950M major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.928
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 4.00GiB freeMemory: 3.34GiB
2019-07-20 16:47:07.850883: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible 
gpu devices: 0
2019-07-20 16:48:53.443303: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect 
StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-07-20 16:48:53.449483: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0
2019-07-20 16:48:53.453555: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N
2019-07-20 16:48:53.462369: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow 
device (/device:GPU:0 with 3050 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, 
name: GeForce GTX 950M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 
5.0)
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 659623925268091428
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 3198956339
locality {
    bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 17589411030014621263
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 950M, pci bus id: 
 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0"
]
```

When I open spyder and type the same 2 line of code:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

Nothing happens and it tries to compile it forever. No errors, no output. I also have tensorflow-cpu environment and when I try some codes that works in tensorflow-cpu environment in gpu environment, also nothing happens. It again takes forever to compile. What is the problem do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it doesn't do anything at all ? Have you tried waiting ? 
I have been across this bug once :

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18652

Most of the people there advice installing the latest nightly version. It seems to be working

Comment: CPU starts to compute in 1 sec so I didn't try to wait more than 2 min with gpu. I will try it and thanks for the link